# TypeScript: Require object to contain a specific property and type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to properly type a function like this:

```
const toggleProperty = <T>(item: T, property: string) => ({
  ...item,
  [property]: !item[property]
});

toggleProperty({name: 'admin', valid: false}, 'valid'); // { name: 'admin', valid: true }
toggleProperty({user: {}, male: true}, 'male'); // { user: {}, male: false}
```

So, I want to pass in the name of the property I want to toggle and it has to be a boolean type.

This is the closest I can get:

```
const toggleProperty = <T extends object>(item: T, property: keyof T) => ({
  ...item,
  [property]: !item[property],
});
```

But I am still able to call the function, without the type safety, like this:

```
toggleProperty({name: 'admin', valid: 'should only accept booleans'}, 'valid');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469417/how-to-extends-pick-omit-all-boolean-props-of-class-to-another-class-or-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the *key* first in the generic, and then you can type the object as extending a Record with that key and `boolean`:

```
const toggleProperty = <
  K extends PropertyKey,
  O extends Record<K, boolean>
>(item: O, property: K) => ({
  ...item,
  [property]: !item[property],
});
```